# Is it possible to register views to the django admin console like model.?

Tags: django, django-views, django-2.2

I tried to register the views in Django 2.2 admin interface, But I am not sure how to add it or can we able to add it.? 
When I tried I am getting the below error.

```
admin.site.register(TargetView)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 102, in register
    for model in model_or_iterable:
TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.urls import path


#Create a Target model
class Target(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Targets'
        app_label = 'apps' # provide app name

# View
def target_view(request):
    return HttpResponse('Target View')

# Register
class TargetAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Target

    def get_urls(self):
        view_name = '{}_{}_changelist'.format(
            self.model._meta.app_label, self.model._meta.model_name)
        return [
            path('target/', target_view, name=view_name),
        ]

admin.site.register(Target, TargetAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

No its not, a view (from the name) is responsible of what will be viewed to the user.

So it can not be controlled by you in the admin, and there is no need for that

But Models is data you might need in `views` which is why you can control in the admin, because sometimes you want to delete, edit or add objects.